# Why is typeof === 'number' not the same as !isNaN(number)

Tags: javascript, numbers, nan, typeof

I have the following code to solve this problem: https://leetcode.com/problems/letter-case-permutation. The end result should be `["a1b2","a1B2","A1b2","A1B2"]` for the string `"a1b2"`

```
function letterCasePermutation(str) {
    const res = [];
    helper(str, res, 0, "");
    return res;
}

function helper(str, res, i, slate) {
    const char = str[i];
    const parsed = parseInt(char, 10);
    //base case
    if(i >= str.length) {
        res.push(slate);
        return;
    }

    // if(!isNaN(parsed)){
    if(typeof parsed === 'number') {
        slate = slate += char;
        helper(str, res, i+1, slate)
    }
    // check for letter
    else if(char.toLowerCase() !== char.toUpperCase()) {
        slate = slate += char.toUpperCase();
        helper(str, res, i+1, slate);

        slate = slate += char.toLowerCase();
        helper(str, res, i+1, slate);
    }
}

letterCasePermutation("a1b2"); //[ 'a1b2' ]
```

The code above doesn't work because when I do:

```
console.log(typeof parsed === 'number') // false
```

The result is always false, even if it is a number (1 and 2). However, when I changed this line:

```
if(typeof parsed === 'number') {
```

to:

```
if(!isNaN(parsed)){
```

It works perfectly. Why is that?

Comment: The code in the question, plus `if(typeof char === 'number')`, gives `true` for me

Comment: The type of `NaN` is "number"

Comment: I´m confuse... where is this line you are changing `if(typeof char === 'number')` ? Is it possible that you are mixing `char` and `parsed` variables ?

Comment: Sorry all, typo, but even if I changed it to `typeof parsed === 'number', the result would still stand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is because **`NaN` is a number**! This is one of those weird gotchas with javascript that bites all of us in the butt every now and then. The correct way to handle this is by using `!isNaN(...)` as you did above.

Read more: https://claritydev.net/blog/what-is-the-type-of-nan/